# Is there a way to turn on LED on chassis panel in Dell blade

Tags: laravel-blade, led

I have a Dell PowerEdge r630 blade which has a LED in chassis panel. I can turn it off or let it blink by running the following command:
   ipmiutil -alarms -iN (N =0 for turning off, N = 255 for blinking)

I wonder if there's some commands to keep LED turned on instead of blinking. I tried some commands of ipmiutil but didn't get it work.

Answer (score 0):

When reading http://ipmiutil.sourceforge.net/man.htm#ialarms, we see :

> -iN    Sets the Chassis Identify feature, which can be an LED  or  some
>      other  alarm.   If  N=0, turn off the Chassis ID, otherwise turn
>      the ID on for N seconds.   N=255 will  turn  on  the  ID  indefi-
>      nitely, if it is IPMI 2.0.

Comment: In the manual when it says turn on, it means blinking in the Dell blade.